# Is LAMP strictly for development purposes?

Tags: security, webserver, lamp

So basically, is LAMP strictly for development purposes or is it fine for production websites as well? I ask this because I have recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows and if LAMP is anything like WANP, it is more aimed towards development than production (live) websites.

Does the same apply for LAMP? I wish to run a small website on Ubuntu and I'm wondering if LAMP is secure enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAMP is definitely production ready, of course with any IP accessible service(s) you have to follow Security Best Practices.

[Secure LAMP server for production use](https://serverfault.com/questions/120345/secure-lamp-server-for-production-use)

Basics;

- hide all version numbers and debug/informations pages
- create a mysql user for each application with hardened passwords
- use regular user accounts (using sudo if needing root permissions)
- use a firewall (iptables) and open specific ports
- do not load modules you don't explicitly need
- apply latest patches/keep packages up to date

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's exactly what I wanted to hear. :) And thanks for the tips!